# Is "What does this dream or meditation experience mean?" a good question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Am I right in thinking that a question of the form "I had this dream, what does it mean?" (like [this one](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/26801/254)) can't be answered well and should be closed, e.g. for the "primarily opinion-based" reason?

---

Related, sometimes people also ask, "I had this experience when meditating", followed by "what does it mean?" and/or "does this mean that I reached the such-and-such stage of meditation?"

Am I right in thinking that (unlike a question about a dream) this kind of question (about a meditation experience) generally shouldn't be closed, and is answerable?

Often, though, if I recall correctly, the only answer posted to this type of question is, "Don't worry about an experience like that, just note it and let it go" (and/or possibly "Don't worry about naming stages").

Occasionally an answer is more substantial, like "no: if you experience X then that's not stage Y".

Comment: I'm not sure what the +1 vote means. I'm going to guess it means "I agree with this suggestion" and not just "This is a good question" (see [Voting is different on meta](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to just close it. Especially when there is no understanding on the part of the person who asks the question.

We are very much conditioned to ask for meaning. That's one of the biggest problems on the path. One has to get passed that. But how do you get passed that?
By hearing over and over again that asking for the meaning is not the right thing, that giving meaning to whatever is leading one away from the right path.

Basically, if you just close the question, don't you take the opportunity away from someone to hear that (s)he is engaging in wrong activity?

But maybe I don't understand the way this platform works well enough yet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only questions worth answering are ones that request clarity on points of Dhamma, so as to clear-up confusion around the doctrine. Questions, the answers of which lead on to Awakening, that develop 'Right View' around the Four Noble Truths.